# Graph displayed in python but cannot find the exported image of the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to export a boxplot to a jpg file. The code is getting executed and the graph is getting displayed, but there is no jpg file in the given destination folder.

```
fig = plt.figure();
boxpl = df.boxplot(column=[<list of columns here>])
fig.savefig("F:\\<full path>\\fig.jpg",format="jpg")
```

I am not using matplotlib to plot the boxplot as it was taking a few hours for only one column whereas the above code segment for multiple columns (around 350000 entries per column) was completed in a few minutes. Is there some issue regarding the destination path, such as for example a file can only be exported to the present working directory?

Comment: What happens with `fig.savefig("fig.png")` ?

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using? It may be the way of describing the path, did you try with / instead of \ ? As pointed out by Jona in its comment, what happens when you just write:

```
fig.savefig("fig.jpg")
```

It may be the format too, did you try png as advised by Jona?

I hope it's helpful.